# Sorting ArrayList by date

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am writing a program and I am trying to sort an ArrayList by date.
Anyone have an idea how to do that?
For example, I have `ArrayList<Oyster> oystercardList;`
and I want to sort the dates of this as the last trip appears on the top.

I have created an object for Date.

Comment: what programming language do you use? And do you have any code already?

Comment: list of what? in which language? `Java`?

Comment: You are going to have to provide quite a bit more info for us to help you. Ideally show the structure of the objects in the list and the code for creating it.

Comment: I am looking at exercise and I am trying to write the solution for it. It is in Java.
creating list for oyster
`ArrayList<Oyster> oysterList;`
then I have class DateTime, so when I run the program it gives me a list of different trips, dates and times.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort custom objects contained in a `Collection` you could use `Collections.sort(java.util.List)` or `Collections.sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)` and implement either the `Comparable` interface or `Comparator` interface.

See the Javadoc for [Collections.sort(java.util.List)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) and  [Collections.sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) for more details.